# request.url showing two urls in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am getting two urls in req.url in http.creatServer() function.
If i console the current url it shows "/favicon.io" and "/test.txt".
I want to show the file "text.txt" content when user try to open the url "http://localhost:3000/test.txt".
Here is my code

```
var fs = require('fs');
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(req,res){
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-type' : 'text/plain'});
    console.log('----',req.url);
 if(req.url === "/test.txt"){
    fs.createReadStream(__dirname + "/test.txt").pipe(res);
 }
 else
 {
    res.end('Hello World!!');
 }
}).listen(PORT);

console.log('Server Running at port ' + PORT);
```

Comment: what is the problem ?

Comment: your console.log is going to fire on every request. so you'll see other urls if those requests come in as well. you need to perform a more robust check on the req.url than just == '/test.txt'

Comment: I am not able to enter the first conditio "req.url === /text.txt" as there are two url in req.url. I just want to print the text file content in response otherwise simple "hello world".Here is screenshot http://prntscr.com/gztb42

Answer (score 0):

Ohh..got your problem. 
Node is Asynchronous event driven programming language. 
so It wont wait unit the file content being read by request operation. 
It will execute another request and your another request is favicon in pipeline. 
so it will always return false. so that you will getting `hello world` every time.

use this and check

`if('txt' == req.url.split('.')[1]){
    var read = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/test.txt");
    res.end(read.toString());
 }`